# Find and replace characters in attributed string with attributes?

Tags: swift, string, replace, character, attributed

I am facing an issue with replacing some characters in an attributed string with some attributed characters.

```
let replaceString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: playerNames[index], attributes: attributes)

taskText.mutableString.replaceOccurrences(of: searchString[Int(index)], with: playerNames[index], options: .caseInsensitive, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: taskText.length))
```

The problem is, that I can't add the replaceString to the replaceOccurrences function because I can't use attributed strings here. Is there any method other method?

I just want to replace some "#1" and "#2" strings with some names like "Anna" but with bold font to make it more visible.

Comment: Find the range, then call https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring/1417045-replacecharacters where you'll have set Anna with bold font for instance.

Comment: Ahhh thanks! I missed to just find the range and replace them afterwards. thanks!